# How to create more number of fields in android screen?

Tags: android

I am working on android project. I need to create a certificate form which contains lot of textfields with different panels. How can I create a screen for that? I have two ways:

1. Using scrollview to display all the fields in one single page.
2. Putting next button and creating each panel in each page.

Can anybody suggest any other ways to create the screen in mobile?

Comment: I think these 2 are popular ways. And you can give a think to Page viewer, too

Comment: You can also have a list which displays the user entries required on press of each list item you can pop up a screen which will take the user entry and on back you can see the user entry added to the list, not a popular one though

Answer (score 1):

you can use the scrollview and to minimize the number of textViews 
look at the following example:-

```
Name: Hello World
Age: 21
City: Every Where
DOB: 10/6/1990
```

the old fashion way is to create a textview for every label, this mean you need 8 textviews,, and this is bad for performance, 
what I suggest to you is create the same output but **with only two textViews**, the first for the left column and the second for right column.

 use StringBuilder in order to fill the left and right column.

This is very good solution, I've worked on Social application the contain the user profiles, and every profile has above 80 view which I was careless about this issue, but when we installed the app on the market,we get a lot of errors and complains about the performance so I had to reduce the textviews and use StringBuilders